# select items with certain "/" in SQL

Tags: android, sqlite, sql

I did a bit of research about sql escape characters and count statements and didnt find a solution to my question. Even though I used stuff like:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE path LIKE '%/_%' ESCAPE '/';
```

I got a table where in a column there is paths so I want to select the items where I have certain number of slashes:

```
ID    DIRECTORY
1     root/A
2     root/B
3     root/A/1/2
4     root/B/1/2
5     root/A/1
6     root/B/2
```

so, how do I select for example the elements that have only 2 slashes??

**Edit 1:** This is to be done in Android SQL-Lite Database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this trick to count occurrences of a character in a string:

```
SELECT LENGTH('path') - LENGTH(REPLACE('path', '/', '')) AS `occurrences`
```

So you can achieve the goal with

```
SELECT id, path FROM
  (SELECT id, path, LENGTH('path') - LENGTH(REPLACE('path', '/', '')) AS `occurrences`
   FROM table) temp
WHERE occurrences = 2
```

However, I expect performance will be terrible. If you are going to query like that, consider adding a column with the path depth so that you can query directly with

```
SELECT id, path FROM table WHERE depth = 2
```

Comment: `CHAR_LENGTH()` might in general be more preferable than `LENGTH()`: the former always counts characters, while the latter counts bytes, which would not always correspond to the character count.

Comment: certainly the idea of occurrences seems to be the key, just need to figure out how to do the query.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE path REGEXP '^([^/]*)/([^/]+)/([^/]*)$';
```

The above expression looks specifically for an optional group of characters not containing `/`, followed by `/`, followed by another group without `/`, followed by `/`, and optionally another set of characters before the end of the string.

So:

```
     /Bxx92/2  -- match
5     root/A/1  -- match
6     root/Bxx92/2  -- match
6     root/Bxx92/2  -- match
7     root/Bxx92/  -- match
6     root/2  -- NO match
```

If there MUST be something before the first and after the last `/`, change the expression to `'^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$'`